# If else PHP statement with variable inside href and li

Tags: php, variables, if-statement, echo, href

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LE80c.png)I have URLs in the database being called by either with $p_camping or $p_hiking

if they're empty, they echo nothing, if the table contains a url for hiking/camping, it will echo a url in an li.

It properly shows empty if the table cell is empty, but it will not echo the href in an li properly, it just spits out the full html link without an li or line break

I've tried countless ways of writing the echos but nothing seems to work, below are two i've tried

```html
<!-- HTML -->

 <ul>
    <? echo "$p_camping" ?>
    <? echo "$p_hiking" ?>
 </ul>
 
 
 <!-- PHP INCLUDE with two variations i've tried out of many -->
 
 $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
  $p_camping = $row['p_camping'];
  $p_hiking = $row['p_hiking'];
    
  
 else
{
  echo "<li><a href='".$p_camping."'>Camping Info</a></li>";  
}


if(empty($row['$p_hiking']))
{
    // it's empty!
    echo " ";
}
else
{
  echo "<li><a href=\"$p_hiking\">Hiking Info</a></li>";  
}
```

Comment: `if` condition missing in your code

Comment: thanks for the response! sorry to sound dumb but can you be more specific, im really new to php... i've tried using elseif if thats what you mean?

Comment: Before 
else
{
  echo "<li><a href='".$p_camping."'>Camping Info</a></li>"

Answer (score 1):

Simple use `!empty()`

```
<?php

echo "<ul>";

if(!empty($p_hiking))
{
    echo "<li><a href='$p_hiking'>Hiking Info</a></li>";  
}

if(!empty($p_camping))
{
    echo "<li><a href='$p_camping'>Camping Info</a></li>";  
}

echo "</ul>";

?>
```

Comment: this gives the same result of urls w/o names unlisted

Comment: Really didn't get you what you mean @Ashley

Comment: where it should write: • stack over flow link

Comment: Check your css that blocking the bullet `style="list-style-type:none;"` @Ashley

Comment: @JToThl its bulleting otherwise, i dont think its a css issue

Answer (score 0):

You shuld write `li` tag inside `ul` try like this

```
<?php
    $url = $p_camping ? $p_camping : ($p_hiking ? $p_hiking : "");
?>
<ul>
    <?php
        if($url){
            echo "<li>$url</li>";
        }
    ?>
</ul>
```

Comment: I have the <ul> in the html

Comment: It just keeps looking like this: 
* Website Link
* 555-555-555
 https://www.nps.gov/hale/learn/news/kipahulu-campground-opens.htmhttps://www.nps.gov/hale/planyourvisit/hiking.htm

and the last two URLs should be bullets on separate lines with the description hiking or camping

Answer (score 0):

Please first check whether p_camping is empty or not

```
 if(!empty($row['p_camping']))
 {
    echo "<li><a href='".$p_camping."'>Camping Info</a></li>";
 }
```

Comment: sometimes it will be empty and sometimes it will not be, depending on the sql row